# What does the phrase "bring up" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from a task management app:

> Linking to events makes it easy for you to **bring up** notes on the day.

I know the lexical meanings of the phrase ["bring up"](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/bring-up), but they don't seem to fit here.

The app makes it easier to manage notes by linking them to events in calendars. Here the word "day" refers to the day when the scheduled event takes place.

Comment: computers : to cause (something, such as a file or picture) to appear on a computer screen
_The system makes it easy to bring up (on the screen) information about any customer._

Answer (score 2):

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bring%20up):

> 3. b. *computers* : to cause (something, such as a file or picture) to appear on a computer screen.

Both **bring up** and **pull up** are frequently used in this context.

For example, from a [blog post](https://www.howtogeek.com/240288/how-to-use-the-on-screen-keyboard-on-windows-7-8-and-10/) about using the Microsoft Windows on-screen keyboard:

> On Windows 10 and 8, there are actually two on-screen keyboards: the basic touch keyboard you can **bring up** from the taskbar, and a more advanced on-screen keyboard in the Ease of Access settings.

The idea is that the keyboard (or the task notes in the app you're discussing) is "hidden" somewhere off-screen and you are **bringing** it out of hiding and putting it **up** on the screen.  This is, of course, not how computers really work, but it is how the experience is designed to feel and talking about it this way makes using the application more intuitive for the user.